# find followed links ignoring file system loops

Tags: find

When I try to find all files/directories, that link to the /tmp folder, I try

```
ls -di /tmp
```

which gives me the inode `4194305` for `/tmp`

Now I would find all files linked to that inode with

```
find / -follow -path /media -prune -inum $(ls -di /tmp |cut -d" " -f1)
```

but this will give me thousands of files system loops detected warnings:

```
find: File system loop detected; `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy

/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/subsystem/event2/device/device/driver/PNP0C0C:00' is part of the same file system loop as `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00'.
find: File system loop detected; `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/subsystem/event2/device/device/driver/LNXPWRBN:00' is part of the same file system loop as `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/subsystem/event2/device/device'.
find: File system loop detected; `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/subsystem/event2/device/device/input/input2' is part of the same file system loop as `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/subsystem/event2/device'.
find: File system loop detected; `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/subsystem/event2/device/event2' is part of the same file system loop as `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/subsystem/event2'.
find: File system loop detected; `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/device' is part of the same file system loop as `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00'.
find: File system loop detected; `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1/subsystem/mice/subsystem' is part of the same file system loop as `/sys/devices/platform/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/subsystem/ttyS0/device/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1/subsystem'.
```

How do I ignore these errors?

Comment: have you tried adding `2> /dev/null` ?

Comment: this seems to work, but it takes 100% CPU. better would be an option, to stop following those loops

Answer (score 2):

The root of your problem is that you told find to follow symbolic links. That's rarely a good idea.

Instead, keep acting on the symbolic links, and filter the ones you want.

You're filtering files by their inode number, but this looks like a mistake: it looks like you're looking for files that are the same as `/tmp`, not files that have the same inode number as `/tmp`. Your command also finds files that have the same inode as `/tmp` but are located on a different filesystem.

Many shells (ksh, bash, zsh, dash) have a `-ef` operator to the `test` command (also spelled `[ … ]`) that tests whether two files are the same.

```
find / -path /media -prune -o -type l -exec ksh -c 'for x; do [ "$0" -ef "$x" ] && printf %s\\n "$x"; done' /tmp {} +
```

Alternatively, you can do this in zsh.

```
print -lr -- /^media/**/*(@e\''[[ $REPLY -ef /tmp ]]'\')
```

Answer (score 0):

Those loops are part of the [`sysfs` pseudo-filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt) that shows kernel data structures and devices. You probably don't want to descend into that (or `/proc` for that matter) if you're just looking for regular files.

You could `-prune` the subtree `/sys`, like you did with `/media` to remove it from the search since it's not likely to contain links to `/tmp`. With `-xdev`, you could also prevent `find` from moving from one filesystem to another, but since symlinks can cross filesystems, you'd then need to list all filesystems separately on the command line. That is, something like

```
find -L / /home /tmp -xdev -inum $inodenum
```

Assuming you have no other filesystems than `/`, `/home` and `/tmp`. That should also remove the need to prune out `/media`, since stuff there is likely separate mounts.

Comment: note that `-xdev` won't work here, as the `-follow` explicitly needs to descend to `/tmp` (which could be, and often is, tmpfs)

Comment: @MatijaNalis, ah, right, I was thinking only about hard links for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not be descending non-physical filesystems (like /proc, /sys etc). Also, are you sure that `find` is doing what you want?

I assume you'd wanted to exclude `/media` for this find, but for that you'd need `OR` (`-o`) instead, like this:

```
find / -follow -path /media -prune -o \( -inum $(ls -di /tmp |cut -d" " -f1) \)
```

Also, the question says you want only symlinks that link to `/tmp` directory itself (and not to any of the files inside). In that case, you'd run something like:

```
find / -path /media -prune -o -path /sys -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o \
  -path /dev -prune -o \( -follow -inum $(ls -di /tmp |cut -d" " -f1) -print \) \
  2> /dev/null
```

(note that position of `-follow` is important, too)